# How to use Lodash orderby with a custom function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using Lodash's [orderby](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) to sort a number of elements based on a key property.

I want to prioritize them by another property (capacity) which is number from 0 to 9. Items with 0 capacity should be sorted at the end and all other items should be sorted by the key.

So capacity property should be converted to a boolean value. I want to do this without changing the original object or adding a new property or making a new array.

Sample data:

```
    [
      {
        "priceChild": 4098000,
        "priceAdult": 4098000,
        "priceInfant": 998000,
        "displayIndex": 4,
        "capacity": 5
      },
      {
        "priceChild": 3698000,
        "priceAdult": 3698000,
        "priceInfant": 898000,
        "displayIndex": 5,
        "capacity": 1
      },
      {
        "priceChild": 3006000,
        "priceAdult": 3980000,
        "priceInfant": 461000,
        "displayIndex": 6,
        "capacity": 0
      },
      {
        "priceChild": 4912000,
        "priceAdult": 6522000,
        "priceInfant": 715000,
        "displayIndex": 7,
        "capacity": 9
      }
    ]
```

This is the sort function that I am using right now:

```
orderBy(results, 'displayIndex', 'asc');
```

I want to do something like this but this code will not work because the ternary operator will not run for every item:

```
orderBy(results, [this.capacity === 0 ? true : false, 'displayIndex'], ['asc', 'asc']);
```

Comment: Please share the code you are currently using to sort the Array and what you have tried to add the condition.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without changing the original object or adding a new property. You do not have capacity key inside you array of objects, so how did you expect to sort by it?

Comment: I have the capacity (corrected the sample data). @LazarNikolic

Comment: Than do this orderBy(results, 'capacity', 'desc');

Comment: I want to sort them by both properties(displayIndex and capacity). Only prioritize the available (capacity > 0) items first. @LazarNikolic

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found out that there is a way to use functions inside orderby properties:

```
orderBy(results, [function(resultItem) { return resultItem.capacity === 0; }, 'displayIndex'], ['asc', 'asc']);
```